# Quomodo "cochlear" a "cochlea" est ortum?

Tags: etymology

Cur **cochlear** a **cochlea** est ortum? Quomodo connectuntur?

In Anglicum liberaliter traductum: What do spoons have to do with snails?

Answer (score 7):

William Whitaker's Words provides a hint in [their definition](http://archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/wordz.pl?keyword=cochlear):

> spoon; **(originally for extracting snails)**; spoonful;

*(emphasis mine)*

Wikipedia [supports this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochlearium), but says it less definitely:

> The word cochlea has a literal meaning of spiral or snail shell, leading many to conclude that the **design of the spoon was so that the handle could be used to get snails** or cockles **out of the shell**.

*(emphasis mine)*

Continued Googling gives very, very few nonmedical results (everything is talking about cochlear implants or infections), and filtering just leaves barely any results. As far as I can tell, this is a question we don't have a definite answer to, but the current hypothesis is this:

***The cochlear was used to extract snails from their shells originally.***

Alternatively, in Latin: ***Cochlear usus primitus erat vellere cochleis crustas***

<sup>I think. My Latin is, as I keep saying, not perfect.</sup>

Comment: (Cavē Latīnitātem tīrōnis.) Intellegisne quōmodo cochleāris forma adiūvit cochleam ex conchā carptus esse? Diū imāginem spectāvī tamen nōn intellegō, sed numquam conātus sum ex conchā cochleam carpere.

Comment: @BenKovitz I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but if I understood it right, no, I don't know how the spoon was used to extract snails.